# For this page, why do I have to use display: inline-block instead of display: inline?

Tags: css

http://christianselig.com/wp/

For the main nav, if I use display: inline, they're displayed as blocks. I added display: inline-block on a whim, and it worked. *scratches head*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now define **your main** `nav li` define `display:inline-block` **or** `flaot:none` because your `.main-navigation li` **define** `float left`

```
nav.main-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Results is

[image]

Comment: I asked why, you told me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

i have check your html code and css this is not valid according to web standards and create many issues if you fix one problem then other problem is arise so kindly check the code

```
nav.main-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

you can add this to your css and it works fine but the navigation merge with your banner headings